# Loading children with lxml overwrite previous loaded elements

Tags: python, lxml

I've written some custom classes in Python, with two functions that load and save the classes to xml files with lxml. The save function and most of load function works, but I have a problem with loading the xml. When I read the `<flows>` and within the `<flow>` tag and element, at each iteration the previous values get overwritten. For example, I have three `<step>` elements with `<flow>` elements: 1 `<flow>` the first `<step>`, 2 `<flow>` the second `<step>` and 3 `<flow>` the third `<step>`. Values seem to be loaded successfully, but in the end the values for each  gets overwritten by the following `<step>`, so I end with having loaded 3 `<step>` with each the same 3 `<flow>`.

Here's the xml:

```
<step>
  <stepnumber>0</stepnumber>
  <steptitle>first step</steptitle>
  <participation>None</participation>
  <tools>tools</tools>
  <rules>rules</rules>
  <actors>
    <actor>first actor</actor>
    <actor>second actor</actor>
  </actors>
  <picture>none</picture>
  <flows>
   <flow>
     <number>0</number>
     <type>Information flow</type>
     <what>bits</what>
     <direction>From the first actor to the second one</direction>
     <firstactor>second actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>first actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
  </flows>
</step>
<step>
 <stepnumber>1</stepnumber>
 <steptitle>second step</steptitle>
 <participation>None</participation>
 <tools>tools</tools>
 <rules>rules</rules>
 <actors>
   <actor>first actor</actor>
   <actor>second actor</actor>
   <actor>third actor</actor>
 </actors>
 <picture>none</picture>
 <flows>
   <flow>
     <number>0</number>
     <type>Financial flow</type>
     <what>none</what>
     <direction>From the first actor to the second one</direction>
     <firstactor>third actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>first actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
   <flow>
     <number>1</number>
     <type>Information flow</type>
     <what>bits</what>
     <direction>From the first actor to the second one</direction>
     <firstactor>second actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>first actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
 </flows>
</step>
<step>
 <stepnumber>2</stepnumber>
 <steptitle>third step</steptitle>
 <participation>None</participation>
 <tools>tools</tools>
 <rules>rules</rules>
 <actors>
   <actor>first actor</actor>
   <actor>second actor</actor>
 </actors>
 <picture>none</picture>
 <flows>
   <flow>
     <number>0</number>
     <type>Financial flow</type>
     <what>none</what>
     <direction>Both directions</direction>
     <firstactor>first actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>second actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
   <flow>
     <number>1</number>
     <type>Information flow</type>
     <what>bits</what>
     <direction>From the first actor to the second one</direction>
     <firstactor>first actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>second actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
   <flow>
     <number>2</number>
     <type>Information flow</type>
     <what>bits</what>
     <direction>Both directions</direction>
     <firstactor>first actor</firstactor>
     <secondactor>second actor</secondactor>
   </flow>
 </flows>
```

Here's the python code:

```
    steplist = doc.xpath("//project/step")
    for k,m in enumerate(steplist):
        stepelements = m.getchildren()
        for l in stepelements:
            if l.tag == "stepnumber":
                self.steps[k] = step()
                self.steps[k].stepnumber = l.text
            elif l.tag == "steptitle":
                self.steps[k].title = l.text
            elif l.tag == "participation":
                self.steps[k].participation = l.text
            elif l.tag == "tools":
                self.steps[k].tools = l.text
            elif l.tag == "rules":
                self.steps[k].rules = l.text
            elif l.tag == "actors":
                self.steps[k].actors = []
                for j,i in enumerate(l.getchildren()):
                    self.steps[k].actors.append(l.getchildren()[j].text)
            elif l.tag == "picture":
                self.steps[k].picture = l.text
            elif l.tag == "flows":
                for s,r in enumerate(l.getchildren()):
                    self.steps[k].flows[s] = flow()
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].number = r.getchildren()[0].text
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].type = r.getchildren()[1].text
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].what = r.getchildren()[2].text
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].direction = r.getchildren()[3].text
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].actor1 = r.getchildren()[4].text
                    self.steps[k].flows[s].actor2 = r.getchildren()[5].text
```

and the result (the three last flows repeated for also the previous ones) is:

```
Flow0 {0: <__main__.flow instance at 0x1005008c0>, 1: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500830>, 2: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500680>}
Flow1 {0: <__main__.flow instance at 0x1005008c0>, 1: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500830>, 2: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500680>}
Flow2 {0: <__main__.flow instance at 0x1005008c0>, 1: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500830>, 2: <__main__.flow instance at 0x100500680>}
```

How can I fix this?
Complete files are available here:
https://github.com/OpenP2PDesignOrg/OpenMetaDesignApp/blob/load/classes.py
https://github.com/OpenP2PDesignOrg/OpenMetaDesignApp/blob/load/test2.meta

Comment: Is there a reason for using xml? can't you just use pickle?

Comment: I've used xml because it's part of a bigger app, and I need the users of the app to be able to read and compare also the xml file. Everything already works in my xml implementation except for this <flow> tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration for `step.__init__` is messed up, since the default argument for the flows argument allocates the same dict instance with the same instance of flow for all values of the flows member. That's evaluated when the definition is loaded, not at each execution of the function.

The more usual way of doing default arguments in Python when what you want passed is something mutable/by-reference is to have the default value be None, and then have some logic in the function where either you do

```
if flows is None:
    self.flows = {0: flows()}
else:
    self.flows = flows
```

or

```
self.flows = flows if flows is not None else {0: flows()}
```

or something along those lines.